# MySql insert last id after each insertion

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i'm trying to insert some rows from one table to another and add last inserted id to first table:

```
INSERT INTO tableA (fooA, fooA2) SELECT fooB, fooB2 FROM tableB;
```

And now i want to add last inserted id into tableB for each row

```
UPDATE tableB set tableA_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

But for multiple records it's wrong. Any idea how to update tableB after each insertion into tableA? Is it possible to do with MySql query, or just write some PHP script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get it done with trigger .